# Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning Exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I am trying to solve Exercise 3.21 in Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning. The question statement can be seen below:

[image: problem here]
My attempt at the solution can be seen below:

[image: my solution here]

It is obvious that I have proved the exact contradict result comparing with the problem description. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please type your questions using MathJax instead of posting images.  Images are not searchable.

Comment: BTW also use \ln instead of ln for the natural logarithm. You can simply copy paste your LaTeX code into your answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice. I will pay attention to those things next time :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you misread Exercise 3.21. It consists of two sub-problems as follows:

> 1. For a real, symmetric (and of course nonsingular) matrix $A$, show that
>      $$
>    \frac{d}{d\alpha}\ln|A| = \operatorname{Tr}\left(A^{-1}\frac{d}{d\alpha}A\right)
>    \tag{3.117}
>    $$
> 2. Derive (3.92) by making use of (3.117).

and you seems to prove the first one.

Suppose $A\mathbf{u}=\lambda(\alpha)\mathbf{u}$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda(\alpha)$ and its corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{u}$. Since $A$ is nonsingular, $\lambda(\alpha)\neq0$ and so $A^{-1}\mathbf{u}=\dfrac{1}{\lambda(\alpha)}\mathbf{u}$. It follows that
$$
\left(A^{-1}\frac{d}{d\alpha}A\right)\mathbf{u} = A^{-1}\frac{d}{d\alpha}\bigl[\lambda(\alpha)\mathbf{u}\bigr] = A^{-1}\bigl[\lambda'(\alpha)\mathbf{u}\bigr] = \lambda'(\alpha)A^{-1}\mathbf{u}= \frac{\lambda'(\alpha)}{\lambda(\alpha)}\mathbf{u}
$$
As the hint of Exercise 3.21, the determinant and the trace are expressed in terms of its eigenvalues. Thus we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Tr}\left(A^{-1}\frac{d}{d\alpha}A\right) &= \sum_i \frac{\lambda'_i(\alpha)}{\lambda_i(\alpha)} = \sum_i\frac{d}{d\alpha}\ln\lambda_i(\alpha) = \dfrac{d}{d\alpha}\sum_i\ln\lambda_i(\alpha) \\
&= \dfrac{d}{d\alpha}\ln\left(\prod_i\lambda_i(\alpha)\right) = \frac{d}{d\alpha}\ln|A|
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I understand your solution, which is quite clear. But I still have one question. Why do I fail to prove the first sub-problem in the problem's situation? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Equation (3.81) says $A=\alpha I+\beta\Phi^T\Phi$. In this case we have simply $\dfrac{d}{d\alpha}A=I$ and $A^{-1}\dfrac{d}{d\alpha}A=A^{-1}$ so that its trace is nothing but $\sum_i\dfrac{1}{\alpha+\lambda_i}$. I do not know why you leave the term $\beta\Phi^T\Phi$ in calculating $\dfrac{d}{d\alpha}A$.

Comment: Oh....I am so stupid... Thanks very much!